# How connect socket.io to angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, socket.io

I am writing an app on nodejs and I have an old version using socket.io but not angular, and I want to develop a new version using angular. I want to use create a new socket when a user connect to my app, and I want that socket is the same in all sections of my app, and I want to use socket.io in angularjs to update some data on DOM when happen an evento and socket notify. I want that manage of sockets is general for all views, so that event is detected on any section of my app. I hobe being enougthly clear. Thanks.

Comment: Please post your code and a description of the specific issue you're having with it (i.e. what you expect it to do and what it actually does).

Answer (score 0):

you can create an angular service and use it wherever you need.

here is the example:

```
(function(){
    'use strict';

    angular.module('-your module name-').service('SocketService', socketService);

    socketService.$inject = ['$rootScope', '$cookieStore'];
    function socketService($rootScope, $cookieStore) {
        var globals = $cookieStore.get('globals');
        var socket = io.connect(
            "-your socket address-",
        );
        var self = this;

        self.on = On;
        self.emit = Emit;

        function On(eventName, callback) {
            socket.on(eventName, function () {
                var args = arguments;
                $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                    callback.apply(socket, args);
                });
            });
        }

        function Emit(eventName, data, callback) {
            socket.emit(eventName, data, function (res) {
                var args = arguments;
                $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                    if (callback) {
                        callback.apply(socket, args);
                    }
                });
            })
        }
    }
})();
```

rest of the logic is up to you... ;)